# jQuery - Load a html file into a div after click on a link

Tags: jquery, html, css, firebase

I want to be able to load a HTML page into a div on my website but i can't get to make it work. I can not use php but I can use client side languages. I am trying to get it to work with jQuery.
Here is what i have tried:

```
    <div id="tutselector">
        <ul>
            <center><li><a class="trigger" href="howtoMakeHeader.html">How To Make A Fancy Header</a></li></center> 
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <div id="tutcontent">
        <center><h1 class="placeholdertext"> Select A Tutorial From The Left </h1><center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.trigger').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var link = $(this).attr("href");
     $('#tutcontent').load(link);
  });
  });
  </script>
```

But it does not seem to be working.

Comment: any errors in the console tab or network tab of devtools?

Comment: there are none can you help me fix it sir

Comment: wait.  you have everything AFTER the `</html>` and `</body>` tags lol.  put the `<script>` stuff before those

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me locally on Firefox but on Chrome I get cross-origin error.
 So try it in some other browser, if you test it locally, you probably have cross-origin issues.
Or upload on some web hosting and try there.
Also, your last `<center>` tag is not closed.